# Java Interface Design Pattern Situation

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, interface, gang-of-four

I am stuck at a problem.
My Problem goes like this.
I have a superclass Animal and two subclasses Human And Bird.
I have a fly method in my super class Animal which will provide an implementation for both the class Human and Bird based on the Flyable Interface.

My Animal class looks like this.

```
public class`Animal{

    public Flyable flyable;

    public void fly()
    {
        flyable.fly();
    } 

 }
```

Human Class looks like this

```
class Human extends Animal {

  Flyable flyable;

  public Human()
  {
   flyable = new CantFly();
  }

}
```

Bird class looks like this

```
class Bird extends Animal {

      Flyable flyable;

      public Bird()
      {
       flyable = new FlyHigh();
      }

    }
```

Interfaces are below

```
public interface Flyable {
   public void fly();
}

public class CantFly implements Flyable{

    @Override
    public void fly()
    {
    Sysout("cant fly");
    }
```

> When I call

```
Animal me = new Human();
me.fly();
```

It gives me NullPointerException

What I m missing here ?.
**I was assuming**. Since I'm calling new Human() it initializes the Flyable interface in superclass Animal. Am I wrong?

I have solved this problem by changing the design of the method.
fly(Flyable flyable).So I don't want that design solution.
I remember facing this problem when I was implementing a search algorithm for an app which will provide a list of result but list item will have different
UI,
https call to different End URLs,
Parsing JSON,
Mapping to Different POJO classes.
Sadly I had to solve that problem with an alternate approach which I have mentioned.

Comment: Why do you have the `flyable` field in the parent ___and___ the sub-classes? What sense should the duplication make?

Comment: In superclass to call the method of Flyable interface . And in subclass to initialize the flyable . Do you see  this as wrong approach ?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. If you need the field in the parent class, then pass the initialization to that class (e.g. `super(new CantFly());`).

Comment: But my SuperClass does not have any parameter in constructor.

Comment: And i think super(something) approach will fail when your super class is an Abstract class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Human` inherits from `Animal`, so all its fields are implicitly "copied" from `Animal`. Therefore, you don't need to redeclare `flyable` again in `Human` and `Bird`.

But you did. This causes the new `flyable` fields in the subclasses to *hide* the original field declared in `Animal`. As a consequence, when you do:

```
flyable = new CantFly();
```

in `Human`, you are assigning a value to the `flyable` in `Human`, not the `flyable` in `Animal`.

Then you did this:

```
Animal me = new Human();
me.fly();
```

`fly` in `Animal` uses the field `flyable` that is declared in `Animal` class, which has not been assigned yet (you only assigned the `flyable` in `Human`)! An NPE occurs as a result.

To fix this, simply remove all the `flyable` fields in the subclasses of `Animal`. This way there is only *one* `flyable` field.

Note

I think this design a little strange. `Human` can't fly, so it shouldn't really have a `flyable` field. In fact, nothing should have a `flyable` field. Among these 3 classes, only `Bird` should implement `Flyable`.

Comment: Even Superclass should not have Flyable interface are u suggesting ?

Comment: @RohitSingh `Animal` shouldn't implement `Flyable` because not all animals can fly.

Comment: But what if in future i decide to introduce a class FlyWithJetPack which will implements Flyable interface . ?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the idea of interface implementation. You don't make lots of concrete classes like `FlyHigh` or `CantFly` and have their instances as fields of `Human` and `Bird`. `Bird` should _directly_ implement `Flyable`. `Human` should have a field called `jetpack` that is of type `Jetpack`. And `Jetpack` should implement `Flyable`. There is no need for a `FlyWithJetpack` class. @RohitSingh